# Drive allocation in a RAID 50 array on a HPE DL380 G9

Tags: raid, raid5, raid0, hpe

I have a DL380 G9 with 12x8TB 3.5" disks:

```
| 1 | 4 | 7 | 10 |
| 2 | 5 | 8 | 11 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 | 12 |
```

In the Smart Array Controller GUI, if I select all 12 disks and assign them to a RAID 50 array, how will the controller divide the disks for the RAID 5 arrays?

Will drives 1-6 and 7-12 inclusive be in two separate RAID 5 arrays, striped for RAID 0? Or will drives 1-3, 4-6, 7-9, and 10-12 be in four separate RAID 5 arrays striped for RAID 0?

If it's the former by default, is it possible to manually configure the array to the latter?

Comment: Don't do R5/R50, it's 2020 and it's been dangerous for a decade, please don't - R1/10 and R6/60 are the only games in town.

Comment: Single parity RAID (5/50) is dead for >600GB HDDs. https://www.securedatarecovery.com/blog/4-ways-that-raid-5-systems-can-lose-data

Comment: ...it's fine for SSDs though. https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/raid-5-was-great-until-high-capacity-hdds-came-into-play-but-ssds-restored-its-former-glory-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of RAID5 sets for RAID0 should be able to configure in raid utility. In your case you can select 2 (6 disks in RAID5), 3 (4 disks in RAID5) or 4(3 disks in RAID5).
From perfromance and capacity perspective - 2 RAID5 sets is most preferable in your case.

P.S. RAID50 tolerates only one disk failure (second disk failure from same RAID5 set will bring whole system down)